# Rails adblock JS file behaving differently in production / development

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, adblock

I have a single file, `ads.js` located in my `assets/javascripts` folder in rails.  It contains one line of code - `canRunAds = true`, which I query elsewhere in my app with the script below.  If it returns `undefined`, I serve up an adblock message.

It works perfectly in development, when I'm testing it, and `canRunAds` will indeed return `undefined`.  In production, however, with adblock turned on - it logs the message `Adblock not detected` - i.e. it doesn't work as expected.  Weirdly, I also get Chrome telling me `ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` for the `ads.js` file... so the file is being blocked, but `canRunAds` is still returning `true`, how?

I've precompiled my assets, and the `ads.js` file is definitely in there.  My knowledge on how rails loads assets is limited enough that I don't know what to Google next to resolve this.  Someone told me rails production will sometimes "reload & autoload all the things whenever" but that's all the info I have to go on...

Any help/pointers would be much appreciated!

```
    function detectAdblock(){
      if( window.canRunAds === undefined){
        console.log("Adblock detected")
        var donateBanners = document.getElementsByClassName("donations");
        for (i = 0; i < donateBanners.length; i++) {
            donateBanners[i].style.display = "block";
            console.log("Banner displayed! " + i)
        }
      }
      else {
        console.log("Adblock not detected");
      }
    }
    window.onload = detectAdblock;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out eventually.

It was working in `development` because rails was serving up static asset files like `ads.js` individually (so adblock picked up on the filename and blocked it).  I think this is because the variable `config.serve_static_files = true` is set (whilst being false in production).

In production, the file contents were being shovelled into `application.js` so the filename wasn’t being picked up.  I threw it into the `public` folder and that did the trick.